# Disable unwanted xss protection in node

Tags: node.js, xss

I never installed any xss protection or someting like that. I realized that i am using helmet but output is protected without helmet too.

Input in database with helmet:

```
 "\"<p>\\\"&lt;p&gt;sdfsdf&lt;strong&gt;sdfsdf&lt;/strong&gt;f&lt;/p&gt;\\\"<\/p>\""
```

Input in database without Helmet

```
"\"<p>fsdfds<strong>fsdfsd<em>fdsfsdfs<\/em><\/strong><\/p>\""
```

But output without helmet in website is still.

```
"<p>fsdfds<strong>fsdfsd<em>fdsfsdfs</em></strong></p>"
```

What can i do this to show correct formating instead of tags?

Add article controller

```
const Article = require("../models/article")

exports.articleAdd = function (req, res) {
    var heading = req.body.heading;
    var author = req.user.firstname;
    var body = req.body.body;
    var slug = req.body.slug;
    var thumbnail = "/uploads/thumbnails/" + req.body.slug + ".jpg";

    // Validation
    req.checkBody("heading", "heading is required").notEmpty();
    req.checkBody("body", "body is required").notEmpty();
    req.checkBody("slug", "slug is not valid").notEmpty();

    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if (errors) {
        res.render("../core/modules/articles/views/addArticles", {
            errors: errors,
            layout: 'cmsLayout',
            heading: heading,
            author: author,
            body: body,
            slug: slug
        });
    } else {
        let article = new Article({
            heading: heading,
            author: author,
            body: body,
            slug: slug,
            thumbnail: "/uploads/thumbnails/" + req.body.slug + ".jpg"
        });

        article.save(function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            } else {
                res.redirect('/');
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: What database is it?

Comment: @Paul I am using MongoDB

Comment: And when you say "Input in database without Helmet" where are you seeing that? in the DB console itself, or after Node has read it out?

Comment: @Paul Is exactly in database (mlab.com)

Comment: Ok.  Dunno; there's nothing in Node that natively does xss protection that I'm aware of, it's all opt-in stuff.  I just tried inserting HTML into a MongoDb from the command line (no Node) and it was fine.  I'm guessing maybe it's something mlab is doing?

Comment: With localhost mongoDB is same issue probably some package or i dont know ... :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry probably my mistake that i didnt say that i am using HANDLEBARS. It was actually problem. To output it like html i need to use `{{{something}}}` insted of `{{something}}`

Comment: ... That's why I asked *where* you were seeing the problem.  It seemed like you were seeing the markup *stored in the database* with the escapes, rather than being published to the page with the escapes.

Comment: Sorry my missunderstanding.